# Evaluate double integral $\int\int F*d$s where $f(x,y,z)=<2x,2y,z>$ and S is the first octant part of $x+y+z=1$ oriented upward

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int\int Fds$ where $f(x,y,z)=<2x,2y,z>$ and S is the first octant part of $x+y+z=1$ oriented upward

How do you solve this? I think you have to parametrize it but I'm not even sure how to do that first step!

Once i get the parametrized equation I think I do $r_\theta \times r_r$ (cross product) 
Then dot product that with parametrized equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parameterize the surface. In this case the surface $S$ is the graph of $z = 1 - x - y$ over the triangle $T$ described $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$, $x + y \le 1$. If you use the simplest parameterization $r : T \to S$ given by $$r(x,y) = (x,y,1-x-y)$$ you get $r_x = (1,0,-1)$ and $r_y = (0,1,-1)$ so that $$r_x \times r_y = (-1,1,-1)$$ which points downward, so in this case you should use $$n = (1,-1,1).$$ Thus
$$ \iint_S F \cdot dS = \iint_T F \cdot n \, dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^x (2x \cdot 1) + (2y \cdot -1) + ((1-x-y) \cdot 1) \, dy dx.$$